# Getting the Date only from the SQL GETDATE() function

Tags: sql

I have seen many different ways to do this but I thought I will share this idea with you all

```
(DAY(Job_Date) = DAY(GETDATE()) 
AND MONTH(Job_Date) = MONTH(GETDATE()) 
AND YEAR(Job_Date) = YEAR(GETDATE()))
```

This will only get records where the `job_date` column is equal to todays date

Comment: 1) You don't specify what SQL you are using, e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle.   2) You don't seem to be asking a question, rather posting a answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `cast(GETDATE() as date)`:

```
where Job_date = cast(getdate() as date)
```

This works in SQL Server 2008+.